# How to customize kendo grid update button?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i am newbie for kendo web UI. I want to implement inline editing grid.when i click to add/edit button we got inline form fields with update button, i want to to get unique id for every row and customized update button functionality so that  i can update my database.

```
<table id="grid11" style="table-layout: fixed; display:none;">
        <colgroup>
                <col style="width:10%">
                <col style="width:20%">
                <col style="width:20%">
                <col style="width:20%">
                <col style="width:30%">
        </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>            
            <th><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:#7ea700; font-size:16px;">Qty</font></th>
            <th><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:#7ea700; font-size:16px;">Unit</font></th>
            <th><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:#7ea700; font-size:16px;">Style Number</font></th>
            <th><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:#7ea700; font-size:16px;">Description</font></th>            <th><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:#7ea700; font-size:16px;">Command</font></th>
        </tr>
       </thead> 
       <tbody>
        <tr>            
            <td>10</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>231234</td>
            <td>ItemDescription</td>
             <td></td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#grid11").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                schema: {
                        model: { id: "id" },
                            fields: {
                                        id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        Qty: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        Unit: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        StyleNumber: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        Description: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    }
                         },
                pageSize: 5
            },
            pageable: true,
            height: 300,
            sortable: true,
            toolbar: [{name:"create",text:"Add"}],
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [
                  {field: "Qty"},
                  {field: "Unit"},
                  {field: "StyleNumber"},
                  {field: "Description"},
                  { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "172px" }]

        });
        $("#grid11").show();
    });
</script>
```

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: And why do you need a custom update button.You can use defalut update button of grid and update your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var len                     =   0;
        $("#grid11").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                            read: "your_read_url",
                            update: {
                            url: "url_for_update",
                            type: "POST",
                            complete: function(result) {

                                }
                            },
                             create: {
                                url: "url_for_add",
                                type: "POST",
                                 complete: function(result) {

                                },
                            },
                            destroy: {
                            url: "url_for_delete" ,
                            type: "POST",
                            complete: function(result) {

                                },
                            }
                        },
                schema: {
                        model: { id: "id" },
                            fields: {
                                        id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        Qty: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        Unit: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        StyleNumber: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        Description: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    }
                         },
                pageSize: 5
            },
            pageable: true,
            height: 300,
            sortable: true,
            toolbar: [{name:"create",text:"Add"}],
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [
                  {field: "Qty"},
                  {field: "Unit"},
                  {field: "StyleNumber"},
                  {field: "Description"},
                  { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "172px" }]

        });
        $("#grid11").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What should be the return format for Read URL and how to get the unique id for each row? Need more Clarification

Comment: Sam return data must be json encoded and assign id as a value of the return array and must be a unique one like set a counter for id from the return data

Answer (score 0):

```
 columns: [
                            { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
                            { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
                            { field: "Title" },
                            { command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px" }]
```

Script

```
  function showDetails(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
    // your logic on command click

                }
```

[**See Kendo Documentation**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html)